# Parent Child relationship in Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I am trying to figure out how to store Parent-Child relationship in Lucene.Net. Java implementation supports it but .Net port is lacking way behind Java implementation, last change to the Lucene.Net code was made almost an year ago.

Flattening the child table won't help because I don't want it to search across different records in child table. For example, here is my schema:

**Resume**

```
Id Name
1  Mike
2  Smith
```

**Experience**

```
Id  ResumeId  CompanyName  FromDate    ToDate
1   1         Microsoft    01/01/2003  12/31/2011
2   1         Google       01/01/2012  11/01/2013
3   2         Google       01/01/2005  12/31/2006
4   2         Yahoo        01/01/2007  12/31/2012
```

So if I flatten records from child table & then want to search for candidates who worked for *Google* between *01/01/2000* and *12/31/2010* then it would return:

```
Id Name
1  Mike
2  Smith
```

Whereas only Smith worked for *Google* between *01/01/2000* and *12/31/2010*.

#### Possible Solution:

How about maintaining two indexes 1 for Resumes & another one for Experiences, filter records using Lucene Query and apply a Join on two result sets on client side (C#)?

I don't think Lucene.Net is being maintained any more (Is that correct or I'm missing something?) so I have started to think on switching to Solr or Elasticsearch.

Comment: What is your question? Lucene will search across only those fields you specify. If you don't want the field searchable, but you do want access to the data, then use `Field.Store.YES` and `Field.Index.NO` for that field.

Comment: No that wasn't the question sorry if I wasn't clear. I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

First, the latest commit to Lucene.Net was a few days ago to the branch [branch_4e](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/tree/branch_4x)
 for version 4 compatibility. The Lucene.Net project is still active and maintained.

This sounds like a typical database query with a simple index on CompanyName, StartDate, StopDate.

The Lucene.Net solution would probably be to use [payloads](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Payload.html). You would associate the company name term with an [to lucene opaque] byte-array containing start- and stop dates.
 You would then need to write your own similary ([example](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/Payloads)) that would return zero for non-matching entries, and combine this with a [PositiveScoresOnlyCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PositiveScoresOnlyCollector.html).

Comment: I looked around Payload & it seems Scores can only be calculated at the time of index (i.e. User provided input can't be used to calculate the scores). Also master is still stuck at 3.0.3, changes from branch_4e are not merged into master for long now. Is it safe to use branch_4e for production?

Comment: No, v4 is not yet ready for production. We welcome testers (and bug reports) of course, but it is not yet fully ported. However, payloads work in v3, so there's not need to upgrade to v4 for this. Payloads are produced during indexing, but the _scoring_ is done at query-time. Your custom similarity-implementation can accept user-input to determine if a payload is within acceptable range (and return 0 when it's not).